# Simple FirebaseApp is crashing after installation

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, instanceid

I am learning to implement firebase in an android studio. And I have studied various tutorials on this subject.
So in order to minimize the chances of making mistakes, I decided to implement a simple token generated scripts in my mainactivity inside the onCreate() method; these codes below:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {

        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {

                Log.w(TAG, "getInstanceId failed", task.getException());
                return;

            }

            String token = task.getResult().getToken();

        }
    });
```

Then the app keeps crashing after generating its apk.

Then following codes were then implemented:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener( MainActivity.this,  new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
     @Override
     public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {

           String newToken = instanceIdResult.getToken();

     }
 });
```

I am using latest dependency :

- firebase messaging:17.6.0
- firebase-core:16.0.8

The problem is each time I generated the APK , the app keeps crashing with error message "app has stopped".
But when I built any other android app without firebase ,the app will work perfectly.

Comment: Please share the error log (can be located under the **Logcat** tab)

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available-libraries check your google services plugin version for your dependency. it should be com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0.